# RegEx exclude one or another character

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I'd like to exclude either one **or** another character with a RegEx.
I have a RegEx that searches the pattern `\[([^\[]+\]\=\>(.*)`.

My problem is the last capture pattern. The string following the `>` should either be followed by a comma or a right parenthesis.

This is my text: `Array([0]=>123,[1]=>Array([a]=>1,[b]=>2))` and I want to get:

```
// match 1
0 = 0
1 = 123

// match 2
0 = 1
1 = Array([a]=>1,[b]=>2)
```

This is my RegEx: `\[([^\[]+)\]\=\>([^,\)]+)\)?` but I get:

```
// match 1
0 = 0
1 = 123

// match 2
0 = 1
1 = Array([a]=>1

// match 3
0 = b
1 = 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character class `[^,\)]` explicitly excludes the comma, so it will never match `Array([a]=>1,[b]=>2)`.

If you are OK with having only one level of nesting, you can try the following:
`\[([^\]]+)\]=>(Array\([^\)]+\)|[^,\)]+)?`

If you want to have arbitarily nested definitions of `Array`, this problem cannot be solved by using regular expressions, because the language you want to parse is not a regular language. You should use a parser generator or write a recursive-descent parser which implements the following grammar:

```
Start : Array
Array : "Array" "(" ElementList ")"
ElementList : "" | Elements
Elements : Element | Element "," Elements
Element : "[" String "]" "=>" Value
Value : Number | Array
Number : [1-9][0-9]*
String : [^\]]+
```

Try looking for parser generators for JavaScript. PEG.js is an exmaple: http://pegjs.majda.cz/

Comment: I'm happy with one level nesting. I actually WANT the second Array completely as string. But when you try my solution and yours (using rubular.com) you will see, that they both result EXACTLY the same

Comment: I fixed the regex, try the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Regex OR syntax is a pipe | e.g. "a|b" will batch a or b